# Pivot table in SQL Server results in error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently I'm trying to learn on pivot table, here is my table diagram.

[image]

I want to generate data row in branch name and column with month with sum total in sales.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         BRANCH.NAME, SALES.TOTAL, TIME.MONTH 
     FROM 
         SALES
     INNER JOIN 
         BRANCH ON SALES.BRANCH_ID = BRANCH.BRANCH_ID
     INNER JOIN 
         TIME ON SALES.TIME_ID = TIME.TIME_ID
    ) AS TABLE1
PIVOT (
    SUM(SALES.TOTAL) FOR TIME.MONTH IN ([APR],[MAY],[JUN])
) PIVOTTABLE
```

it shows an error:

> The column prefix 'SALES' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Is it my table structure got problem or just my query are wrong?

Comment: huh? sorry i don't get it...

Comment: @Roberto still  doesn't work.

Comment: Your TITLE is IN ALL CAPS. There's no reason to SHOUT HERE. We can read just fine. Look at all of the other questions on the main page, and you'll see that no one feels the need to SHOUT HERE to GET ATTENTION to their questions. (Your title is entirely lacking in content as well; SQL Server is available information from the tags, and *Pivot Table* is not a question or problem description. You should  [edit] to fix both of those issues.)

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry about that, don't really know tile in caps mean shout in here. Btw, Thanks

Comment: @JakeCube: writing in ALL CAPS is considered shouting in EVERY forum - not just here.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   SELECT * FROM 
 (
    SELECT  BRANCH.NAME,SALES.TOTAL,TIME.MONTH 
    FROM SALES
    INNER JOIN BRANCH 
    ON SALES.BRANCH_ID=BRANCH.BRANCH_ID
    INNER JOIN TIME 
    ON SALES.TIME_ID=TIME.TIME_ID
  )AS TABLE1
PIVOT (
SUM(TABLE1.TOTAL) FOR TABLE1.MONTH IN ([APR],[MAY],[JUN])
) PIVOTTABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Sales` and `Time` prefix or use `TABLE1` instead:

```
PIVOT (
    SUM(TOTAL) FOR MONTH IN ([APR],[MAY],[JUN])
) PIVOTTABLE
```

Comment: Yup. To further expound on Giorgi's answer: the pivot occurs after the query, so pivot on the subquery columns. I think SUM(TABLE1.TOTAL) would work -- an unnecessary step, but just to show you which column this is actually referring to.